# Algorithm to permute parts of vector without storing all permutations in memory

Tags: algorithms, permutations, combinations

Given a vector of 48 elements,

```
[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48]
```

and an associated number label for each element,

```
[1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 4 4 6 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 9 9 9 9 9 9],
```

how can all possible permutations be generated such that elements are permuted with other elements that share the same label. For example, the first element,

```
1
```

is alone in the set of elements with label "1" and, therefore, there exists only one possible arrangement for this set. But elements

```
2 through 10
```

are labeled "2" and therefore permute amongst themselves in 9! different ways. Because the total number of possible permutations, with the restriction that each element is permuted only with elements sharing a common label, is

```
 1! 9! 8! 6! 1! 9! 8! 6! = 1.1098e+26,
```

memory storage is quickly exceeded. Therefore, it would be nice to have an algorithm that generates permutations one at a time, on the fly, rather than all at the same time.

Comment: Important intermediate question: Can you do it if all the labels are the same? In other words, can you find an algorithm that outputs _all_ permutations of an array, without using too much memory? And would "keep track of how many permutations we've done so far" be too much memory to ask for? Seeing how that would take less than 100 bits I should hope not.

Comment: maybe PARI/GP's new forperm ( version 2.10.0)?

Comment: For $10^{26}$ permutations, _storage_ does not need to be exceeded, but "time left before the sun becomes a red giant and swallows the earth" will probably be exhausted before you finish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For now, I'll assume all the labels are the same, so you have a vector of length $n$ and want to cycle through all $n!$ permutations.

It is best explained by example. Suppose your current permutation is

$$(3,2,6,5,4,1)$$

- Start from the right, the end of the vector, in this case a $1$.
- While the element to the left is bigger than the current element, move to the left. In this case you move to the left to the $4$, the $5$, and then the $6$. At that point you stop because the next element $2$ is smaller than $6$. In this way you have identified a decreasing tail $6,5,4,1$ and the next element, a $2$, that does not belong to it.
- Now you have to swap the $2$ with the next-higher element that lies somewhere to its right. This is simple to find, because we know all those elements in this tail are in decreasing order. In this case the next-higher element is the $4$. After the swap we get the intermediate result, $(3,4,6,5,2,1)$.
- As a final step, reverse the order of the tail, i.e. of all the elements to the right of the one you just swapped. The result is:

$$(3,4,1,2,5,6)$$

That's it. If you keep applying this procedure, you will generate the permutations in lexicographical order. If you repeat the procedure again, you get:

$$(3,4,1,2,6,5)$$

Note that now we did a swap, but the tail was of length $1$ so there was nothing to do in the final step. Applying the procedure again, we get the intermediate result $(3,4,1,5,6,2)$ and finish with the next permutation:

$$(3,4,1,5,2,6)$$

The next permutations are then

$$(3,4,1,5,6,2)\\(3,4,1,6,2,5)\\(3,4,1,6,5,2)\\(3,4,2,1,5,6)\\(3,4,2,1,6,5)\\(3,4,2,5,1,6)\\(3,4,2,5,6,1)\\(3,4,2,6,1,5)$$

If in the second step you find that whole permutation is decreasing, i.e. is just a tail with no element to its left, then you have reached the end. You can however let it "overflow" by reversing the tail to start again at the first permutation.

---

You can easily extend this to deal with multiple labels. Apply the procedure to the last set of elements with the same label. If that worked normally, you are done. However if the permutation overflowed, then you have to "transfer a carry" to the next set, i.e. also apply the procedure to the next label's set of elements.

Comment: Thanks! Does this algorithm have a name?

Comment: Not that I know of. [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Generation_in_lexicographic_order) says "The method goes back to Narayana Pandita in 14th century India, and has been frequently rediscovered ever since."

Answer (score 1):

Yes you could find a set of generators for the group.

1. For example switching every pair requires $\mathcal O(n^2)$ sparse matrices (actually only need to store pairs of integers $\in [1,n]$ to switch because each other $1$ is along the diagonal) is a great improvement in itself and
2. it is also easy to realize it is enough to concatenate those pair-switchings to create all permutations since many sorting algorithms you learn in undergrad and grad rely on switching pairs of elements and are able to sort any vector.

For example for $4$ elements we will be Ok with storing ($3+2+1$):

$$P_{12} = \left[\begin{array}{cccc}
0&1&0&0\\1&0&0&0\\0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&1\end{array}\right], P_{13} = \left[\begin{array}{cccc}0&0&1&0\\0&1&0&0\\1&0&0&0\\0&0&0&1
\end{array}\right], P_{14} =\left[\begin{array}{cccc}0&0&0&1\\0&1&0&0\\0&0&1&0\\1&0&0&0\end{array}\right]\\P_{23}= \left[\begin{array}{cccc}
1&0&0&0\\0&0&1&0\\0&1&0&0\\0&0&0&1\end{array}\right], P_{24} = \left[\begin{array}{cccc}1&0&0&0\\0&0&0&1\\0&0&1&0\\0&1&0&0
\end{array}\right], P_{34} = \left[\begin{array}{cccc}
1&0&0&0\\0&1&0&0\\0&0&0&1\\0&0&1&0\end{array}\right]$$

We need to keep track of 6 generative permutations, a lot less than the 24 total permutations. But of course more impressive for larger $n$ as $n!$ grows so much faster than $\frac {n(n-1)} 2$.